# I keep getting emails from people who attach their email to mine

Tags: security, gmail

I quite often get emails from google saying that someone added my email address as their recovery email.

I always dettach the email, but how do they do this?

Gmail allows it without entering my password?

Comment: Well really, they can type any email address in existence for their recovery email. It is the same idea as if people sign your email address up for spam on a site. You really have no control of this other than dealing with the emails you get from it or having google automatically detect them as spam and delete them.

Comment: the last email google sent me had the subject 'someone has your password'.

Comment: If it is actually your account then change your password immediately. If it is not your account, then you should just delete it or set up email filters to do it for you.